# Spend x points to play a game and get 2x points with probability P and get nothing with probability (1-P). What's the probability of getting y points?

Tags: probability

In a game, you can spend any positive real number of points (let it be $x$) to play it. You can win $2x$ points with probability of $P$, or get nothing with probability of $(1-P)$.

At beginning, you have 1 points, and you can play the game as many time as you want. If you adopt the best strategy, what's the probability of ending up with at least Y points?

You can't play the game any more if your point is below or equal to 0. Also, if you reach $Y$ points, you will stop immediately.

For $P > \frac{1}{2}$, The expected value of winning points is greater than zero. So it's seems that the probability of getting Y points is $1$. What about $P \le \frac{1}{2}$?

Also, what's the best strategy?

The the best strategy is to maximize the probability of reaching $Y$.

Comment: You can keep playing even when you have negative points? "The best strategy" means what here - get the maximum total value, or the best chance of reaching $Y$?